# why nested foreach within javascript loop not working?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I am trying to check if the answers from a user are correct. The answers of the user are stored in variable "stad". The correct options are stored in variable "collectie". However, this variable is an array with a nested array. So i first loop through the "collectie", check if the collectie element is not an array and if not, check that the submitted value is within this collectie element.

If the collectie element is an array, i have to alter a little bit the function so the variable checks whether the answer is within the nested array.

I have the following:

```
function nakijken() {
var collectie = ["parijs", "8", "ijsselmeer", ["Volkswagen", "Audi", "Opel", "Porsche", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Mercedes-Benz"],
["Texel", "Vlieland", "Terschelling", "Ameland", "Schiermonnikoog"]];
var stad = [];
var a = 0;
stad.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
collectie.forEach(uitpakken);
function uitpakken(antwoord) {
    if (!Array.isArray(antwoord)) {
        stad.forEach(myfunction);
        function myfunction(item) {
            if (antwoord.includes(item.value.toLowerCase())) {
                item.style.background = "green";
                a++;
            } else {
                antwoord.style.background = "red";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        antwoord.Foreach(uitpakken);
        function uitpakken(antwoord) {
        stad.forEach(mysecondfunction);
            function mysecondfunction(item) {
                if (antwoord.includes(item.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    item.style.background = "green";
                    a++;
                } else {
                    antwoord.style.background = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, i get the error: item.value is not defined.
Within the console, i see that item is a collection of inputs, and not a single input.

Why is this not working?

Comment: item is a string or array. It has no value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main probelm seems to be in

```
stad.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
```

because that pushes the returned element collection into `stad` as a single reference (and also an HTML collection is not a real array). Instead, you can use

```
stad = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
```

Second, in the first branch of the `if` statement, where `antwoord` is not an array, what does it mean `if (antwoord.includes(item.value.toLowerCase()))` ? You probably want to use a simple comparison like `if (antwoord === item.value.toLowerCase())` .

Third, there is a typo `Foreach` instead of `forEach` in one place.

Fourth, are you sure you want to loop through all the input boxes for each entry in the main correct answers array? Isn't each input box corresponding to a specific question with a specific correct answer or set of correct answers?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` does *not* return an array, it returns a live HTML collection, which cannot be iterated over with forEach, although you can refer to its elements by index number (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName).
In addition, you are then pushing this entire collection to the `stad` array as one item, which is why you see `item` is a collection of inputs -- that collection (of live HTML elements) is the *only* item in the `stad` array.

As another answer suggests, instead of using `stad.push`, simply assign a real array to `stad` by creating an array from the collection:

> `stad = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));`